# If $x+y+z=2$, what is the max value of $xyz^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

I have tried to find the max value of $xyz^2$ if $ x+y+z=2 $ using variation of $f(x,y,z)$, but I don't know how I can calculate the derivative of a function of three variable. If my idea is correct, then I want to ask if there is any simple way to do that.

**Note**: $x$, $y$, $z$  are real.

Comment: are the $x,y,z$ assumed to be positive?

Comment: Is it $x\cdot y \cdot z^2$ or $(xyz)^2$?

Comment: Without more restrictions, I think $f(x,y,z)$ couldn't have a maximum.

Comment: -1 People pointed out as soon as you posted the question that you need to require $x,y,z$ non-negative. Otherwise you can take $x=-N,y=-N,z=2N+2$ and get $xyz^2=4N^2(N+1)^2$ arbitrarily large. Please edit the question.

Answer (score 4):

By AM-GM inequality twice: $xy \le \dfrac{(x+y)^2}{4} \implies xyz^2 \le \dfrac{(x+y)^2z^2}{4}= \dfrac{(2-z)^2z^2}{4} \le \dfrac{1}{4}\cdot \left(\dfrac{2^2}{4}\right)^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}$, and this is the max value you sought. It occurs at $z = 1, x = y = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: you can not use $AM-GM$ the $x,y,z$ are assumed to be reals

Comment: What is AM-GM ?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Why not? Do you see any square root?

Comment: Pleas what do you meant by AM-GM ,

Comment: no i don't see any square root

Comment: @JackWonder Did you try to google it?! It is the inequality of arithmetic-geometric means.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner There you go: then the AM-GM can be used.

Comment: i think it is a local maximum

Comment: @egreg Of course, but then it might result pretty trivial. For example, with $\;x<0\;,\;\;y>0\;$ , we trivially have $$xy\le\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)^2$$What you may not have is $\;\sqrt{xy}\le\frac{x+y}2\;$ as the square root requires that product to be non-negative

Comment: @egreg In fact I didn't read the answer, only addressed the fact that it can be used...and indeed: the last inequality seems to be unjustified. But the AM-GM is correctly applied...though I can't see where "twice" .

Comment: You seem to believe that $z^2(2-z^2)^2\le 1$, which is obviously false.

Comment: $z^2(2-z)^2\leqslant 1$ is unjustified, if $z \in \mathbb R$.  For e.g. consider $z=-10$.

Comment: I think I understand the claim which could be put more explicitly $z(2-z) \le \frac{(z+ 2-z)^2}{4} = 1. And you’re just doing this trick twice. However you need that $z(2-z) /gt 0$ for this trick to be used twice. (Think explicitly, and you should see the error)

Comment: @DeepSea: $f(x,y,z)=1/4$ max? Consider $f(2,2,-2)$. See the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x,y,z>0$ by [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) we have

$$\frac{x+y+\frac{z}2+\frac{z}2}4\ge \sqrt[4]{\frac{xyz^2}{4}}$$

$$\iff2=x+y+\frac{z}2+\frac{z}2\ge 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{xyz^2}{4}}$$

thus

$$xyz^2\le \frac14$$

and maximum occurs for $x=y=\frac{z}2=\frac14 \implies (x,y,z)=\left(\frac14,\frac14,\frac12\right)$.

Note also that for $xy<0 \implies f(x,y,z)<0 $.

For $x, y$ both negative let $x=y=-t$ with $t>0$ we have $z=2-(x+y)=2+2t$ and then

$$xyz^2=t^2(2+2t)^2\to +\infty$$

Therefore $f(x,y,z)$ has not maximum in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and has maximum in the restriction to $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \{(x,y)|x<0 \land y<0\}$.

Comment: then it must be $$x>0,y>0,z>0$$!

Comment: Well, in fact it must be $\;xy\ge0\;$ ...

Answer (score 2):

The function has no maximum on that plane. Indeed, fix $y=1$, so $z=1-x$ and we have
$$
f(x,1,1-x)=x(1-x)^2
$$
that has limit $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. It has no minimum either, because the limit for $x\to-\infty$ is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x=y=10$ and $z=-18$, then $x+y+z=2$ and $f(x,y,z) = 32,400.$ There is no maximum.  Using Lagrange multipliers, it's easy to find the local max at $x=y=1/2$, $z=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$ x=t, y=-1,z=2-t$$ then $$x+y+z=1$$ and$$xyz^2= -t(2-t)^2$$ which grows without bound.

Thus There is no maximum or minimum for this function.